# iCal compliant recurrence rule for bimonthly pay period

Tags: icalendar, recurrence

I'm trying to create a iCal compliant recurrence rule which should reflect the pay days for people who get paid bi-monthly. The details for recurrence rules can be found on the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10).

Here are the rules:

- The individual gets paid on the 15th and the last day of the month.
- In the event that the 15th or the last day of the month occurs on a weekend, they should get paid on the Friday before then.

What I have so far:

```js
[
"RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=15;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR", // this will select the 15th if it's not on a weekend 
"RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYSETPOS=-1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;", // this correctly selects the last weekday of the month
]
```

The problem with this approach is if the 15th falls on a weekend, the event is omitted.

I'm not sure if this is something that can be modeled. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4303290) solved the problem.

For the 15th I needed the following rule:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSETPOS=-1;BYMONTHDAY=13,14,15;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
```

> So thats the last weekday before the 15. I had to add the 13,14,15 since those are esentially the only possible dates that I can occur. (Worst case would be that the 15th is Sunday, so the preceding Friday would be the 13th

The two rules together got me what I needed!